# PostgreSQL: UNIX Time Dynamic query

Tags: postgresql, powerbi, unix-timestamp

I'm making a Power BI report where data that I need to show is stored in a PostgreSQL database.

In the table where I query there is data from 4 years ago until today, but for my report I only need the last week of records (I know that I can filter using Power BI but my goal is make the lighter query as possible).

The fields of the database related to time, are in UNIX Timestamp, so I'm filtering it now by this way:

```
 SELECT
    DATABASE.INCIDENT_NUMBER
    ,DATABASE.SUBMITTER
    ,DATABASE.CREATE_DATE 
    ,DATABASE.MODIFIED_DATE
    ,DATABASE.CLOSED_DATE
    ,DATABASE.SUBJECT
FROM
    DATABASE
    
WHERE
    1643670000 < DATABASE.CREATE_DATE

ORDER BY DATABASE.INCIDENT_NUMBER, DATABASE.CREATE_DATE ASC
```

That is fine, but I want to improve it making a dynamic query which returns the records from last week till today, without putting a constant of UNIX timestamp.

How can I make that?

Comment: `where extract(epoch from date_trunc('week', current_date)) <= database.create_date`

Comment: https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/

Answer (score 2):

That's an excellent example why it is a bad idea to store timestamps as numbers. The correct data type is `timestamp` or `timestamp with time zone`.

If you had used the correct data type, your condition would be as simple as

```
WHERE current_date - 7 < database.create_date
```

But with numbers, you have to convert back and forth:

```
WHERE to_timestamp(EXTRACT('epoch' FROM current_date) - 7) < database.create_date
```